# A simple stock exchange app

Tags: python, python-requests

I've struggled to make a small stock project for almost 5 hours (biggest one so far).

The project is simple: I've chosen a stock (Tesla in my case) and I've decided to get a message on my phone with the last 3 news from Tesla, everytime the stock increased/decreased by 5%.

I've used 3 API's and some JSON data formatting.

Hope you can give me some advice on what I could've done better so I can grind more since I'm new :).

Thank you!

```py
import requests
import datetime as dt
from twilio.rest import Client
import os

API_KEY = os.environ.get('API_KEY')
NEWS_KEY = os.environ.get('NEWS_KEY')
account_sid = os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_SID')
auth_token = os.environ.get('AUTH_TOKEN')
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER = ''
FROM_PHONE_NUMBER = ''

stock_url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=TSLA&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY'
news_url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=tesla&apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY'


def percentage(part, whole):
    if whole == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)


response_stock = requests.get(url=stock_url)
response_stock.raise_for_status()

response_news = requests.get(url=news_url)
response_news.raise_for_status()

ytday = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(1)
the_day_before_ytday = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(2)
yesterday = ytday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
the_day_before_yesterday = the_day_before_ytday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

stock_data = response_stock.json()
news_data = response_news.json()
yesterday_price = 0
the_day_before_yesterday_price = 0

for (date, dateum) in stock_data['Time Series (Daily)'].items():
    if date == the_day_before_yesterday:
        the_day_before_yesterday_price = dateum['4. close']
    if date == yesterday:
        yesterday_price = dateum['4. close']

if yesterday_price == 0 or the_day_before_yesterday_price == 0:
    try:
        raise KeyError('Invalid range or one of the days is in weekend.')
    finally:
        pass


difference = float(the_day_before_yesterday_price) - float(yesterday_price)
percent = percentage(round(difference, 2), the_day_before_yesterday_price)

i = 0
if percent > 5 or percent < -5:
    for article in news_data['articles']:
        while i < 3:
            message = client.messages.create(
                body=article['description'],
                from_=FROM_PHONE_NUMBER,
                to=YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER
                )
            break
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Some good things - you use env vars, you use requests and check the return status, you use the datetime module.

`os` seems unused so remove it.

Don't bake query parameters into your URLs. Use requests `param`.

The `percentage` function is not really useful. Internal (non-printed) program logic usually shouldn't deal in percentages, but fractions.

Be nice to your server. Tell it what content type you want out of the request via `Accept`.

Don't loop through a dictionary when you can do a key lookup.

Don't `try/raise/finally/pass`. That seems like a useful error, so remove the `try`. Also, that isn't a `KeyError`; it's more like a `ValueError`.

Don't do a dual comparison to `5`, `-5`. Do a single comparison to `abs() > 0.05`.

`i` and your `while` don't seem to do anything, so remove them.

Don't use `0` to indicate null; use `None`.

Don't download your news source unless you need it.

### Suggested

```py
from datetime import timedelta, date
from decimal import Decimal
from typing import Optional

import requests

YOUR_PHONE_NUMBER = ''
FROM_PHONE_NUMBER = ''


with requests.get(
    url='https://www.alphavantage.co/query',
    params={
        'function': 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED',
        'symbol': 'TSLA',
        'apikey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    },
    headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
) as response_stock:
    response_stock.raise_for_status()
    stock_data = response_stock.json()


def get_price(days_ago: int) -> Optional[Decimal]:
    day = date.today() - timedelta(days=days_ago)
    maybe_price = (
        stock_data['Time Series (Daily)']
        .get(day.isoformat(), {})
        .get('4. close')
    )
    return maybe_price and Decimal(maybe_price)


yesterday_price = get_price(1)
day_before_yesterday_price = get_price(2)

if yesterday_price is None or day_before_yesterday_price is None:
    raise ValueError('Invalid range or one of the days is in weekend.')

difference = abs(yesterday_price/day_before_yesterday_price - 1)
print(f'Stock change: {difference:.1%}')
if difference > 0.05:
    with requests.get(
        url='https://newsapi.org/v2/everything',
        params={
            'q': 'tesla',
            'apiKey': '',
        },
        headers={'Accept': 'application/json'},
    ) as response_news:
        response_news.raise_for_status()
        news_data = response_news.json()

    for article in news_data['articles']:
        print(article['description'])
```

Comment: Thanks buddy!

Whole new 'level' of interpretation of this problem. Also hole new way of seeing on how to solve these.

Thank you, really appreciate it!